Load a class instance using parameterized constructor with ServiceLoader
I am using java ServiceLoader to load the instances of an SPI. ServiceLoader uses the public default no-args constructor to load the service providers.
I want to load the instances using a parameterized constructor instead for my requirements.
Here's a sample provider interface
package com.myOrg.check.access;

public interface IRuleValidator{
    void validate();
}

Sample provider
package com.myModule.myService.check.access;

public class MyRuleValidatorProvider{
    private MyDto myDto;
    public MyRuleValidatorProvider() {

    }
    public MyRuleValidatorProvider(MyDto myDto) {
        this.myDto = myDto;
    }
    @Override
    void validate() {
        //Here I am using this.Dto to validate some rules
    }
}

Provider Loader
ServiceLoader<IRuleValidator> loader = ServiceLoader.load(IRuleValidator.class);
while(loader.iterator().hasNext()) {
    IRuleValidator myImpl = loader.iterator().next(); // This will load myImpl Variable using default no-args constructor
}

As, shown in Sample Provider, I am using MyDto object to validate some rules but serviceLoader only loads the instances using default no-args constructor whereas I require the one with parameterized constructor.
So, far to overcome this issue I am using something like this:
Provider Loader
// part of a method, which get myDto as an argument
getValidator(MyDto myDto) {
    ...
    
    ServiceLoader<IRuleValidator> loader = ServiceLoader.load(IRuleValidator.class);
    
    while(loader.iterator().hasNext()) {
        IRuleValidator myImpl = loader.iterator().next();
        Constructor<?>[] constructors = myImpl.getClass().getDeclaredConstructors();
        for (Constructor<?> constructorIter : constructors) {
                        Class<?>[] parameterTypes = constructorIter.getParameterTypes();
            if (parameterTypes.length == 1) {
                if (myDto!= null && parameterTypes[0].equals(myDto.getClass())) {
                    constructor = myImpl.getClass().getConstructor(Class.forName(myDto.getClass().getName()));
                } else {
                      constructor = myImpl.getClass().getConstructor(Class.forName(IMyDto));
                       }
                }
            }
        }
    IRuleValidator newImpl = (IRuleValidator) constructor.newInstance(myDto);
    
    ...

}

This works perfectly but in peer review I have got opinions that this is not at all performance friendly. I haven't got any solution and hence want to know if there is a way to load an instance using parameterized constructor?
What is wrong with my solution? how does it impact the performance and is there any other shortcomings in this approach?

This question is similar to: Loading services with different fields using ServiceLoader in Java. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This code should not be performance relevant anyway, as services should be looked up once, at the beginning. Still there’s no point in performing another constructor lookup where you already got the constructor. Class.forName(myDto.getClass().getName()) evaluates to the same object as myDto.getClass() and since you’ve already checked that myDto!= null && parameterTypes[0].equals(myDto.getClass()) is true, the entire myImpl.getClass().getConstructor(Class.forName(myDto.getClass().getName())) produces an object equal to constructorIter, so use constructorIter in the first place.

But the better solution still is to follow this answer

As far as I am aware it is not possible to pass constructor arguments to Java ServiceLoader, but you can solve your problem with a small workaround. Instead of providing an instance of your service directly with the ServiceLoader, first load a factory object, which can be used in turn to provide an instance of the Service.
For example you could have :

public class MyRuleValidatorProviderFactory{
    public MyRuleValidatorProviderFactory() {

    }

    public MyRuleValidatorProvider create(MyDto myDto) {
        return new MyRuleValidatorProvider(myDto);
    }
}


and have that loaded by ServiceLoader instead of directly loading the Service. You could of course make some interface out of it if necessary.

You have a problem, which is: "I need to send a parameter to my service provider; not per call to the thing the service provider does (if that was the case, you'd just add a param to the void validate() declaration), but to the SP itself".
And you thought: "I know! I'll add a constructor that takes this parameter! Oh, wait, now I have questions about how to make that work with the serviceloader, I better go ask on SO".
But, the 'I know!' part of that was wrong. 'add a parameter to the constructor' is not how you solve the problem "I need to send a parameter to the service provider itself".
Don't do this
Constructors don't play the type system game. You can't make an interface that states: "Any classes that implements this interface must have a 1-arg constructor, and that 1 arg needs to be type MyDto. Thus, you have to resort to reflection, and when you have to resort to reflection, you lost. That truly is the solution of last resort, and.. we haven't gotten to 'last resort' territory yet.
You instead have 2 ways to do this:
The simple solution that leaves a bad taste
Just.. add a param to void validate() - make that void validate(MyDto myDto) Yes, the parameter will be the same for each and every call to validate. So what?
The slightly more complex general solution
Factories.
It is clear that the creation of instances of IRuleValidator is not something that SPI can do for you. After all, to create an instance, you need to know both the fully qualified name of one (which Service Provider Loader can get, that's what SPI is for), and that parameter which the the service loader does not have.
So, instead define this interface:
// prefixing `I` to interfaces is bad, don't do that.
public interface RuleValidatorFactory {
  RuleValidator create(MyDto dto);
}

and make an SPI setup for that. Now SPI can do what it does, which is, instantiate classes using the public no-args constructor based on names gleaned from service definition files in the META-INF/services.

…and this pattern (factories) is what is used all over the place. The service loader doesn’t look up FileSystem implementations but FileSystemProvider. It does not look up Charset implementations but CharsetProvider. And so on…
